# Search across Excel worksheets and return a value based on where clause with hierarchy?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to return a lead sales person based on the products that are used by the customer

I have a workbook that contains a number of worksheets within it. The first worksheet is a summary worksheet with a search field and a button that when clicked returns specific column data from the other sheets. 
The other sheets are based on product, we have three products which equals three worksheets. The columns in each of those worksheets is the same with the data different from product to product.

I have been asked to add a new column, "sales person" to each product worksheet with the aim of pulling that data into the summary worksheet when a new search is executed. 
The problem I am facing is that there is a lead sales person when multiple products are used by the customer. Though each product has a sales person, it is a different person per product and where multiple products are used by the customer one of the sales people assumes the role of lead sales person

**The workbook structure is**
Worksheet 1 is the summary sheet and will have a new column title called "lead sales person"
worksheet 2 is for windows and the sales person is Jack
Worksheet 3 is for doors and the sales person is Mary
Worksheet 4 is for tiles and the sales person is Sarah

**Scenarios for returning the correct lead sales person**

1 - WHERE customer product list = doors AND windows 
THEN the sales person that should be retrieved is Jack

2 - WHERE customer product list = tiles and windows 
THEN then the sales person that should be retrieved is Sarah

3 - WHERE customer product list = windows, doors and tiles 
THEN the sales person that should be retrieved is Sarah

4 - WHERE customer product list = a single product 
THEN the name of the sales person retrieved should be the name of the person in the sales person column on that worksheet

NB: The common link between each worksheet is the Customer ID field. This is what allows us to see all products that a customer has when executing the query below.

Ideally what I need is something that is flexible so that there would be no need to hard code people's name into the code to retrieve the lead sales person

Below is the code that I have written for the search across worksheets as it currently is. It works great, just need to find a way to add the above! 
Thanks in advance.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub OptionCompareText()


End Sub

Sub SearchMultipleSheets()

    'The 5 in the line below is the maximum array value which further down is the arr(i, 5) = ws.Name entry
    Dim arr(999, 5) As Variant, r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, s As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set r = Sheets ("Sheet2").Range("A2:A & Lastrow)

    With Sheets(1)
        s = Range("c1").Value
        .Range("a3").Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count).ClearContents
    End With
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> Sheets(1).Name Then
        With ws
            For Each r In .Range("a2", .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                If r.Value & r.Offset(0, 1).Value & r.Offset(0, 2).Value & r.Offset(0, 3).Value Like "*" & s & "*" Then
                    arr(i, 0) = ws.Name
                    'arr(i, 1) = r.Value
                    arr(i, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    arr(i, 2) = r.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    arr(i, 3) = r.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    arr(i, 4) = r.Offset(0, 4).Value

                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next r
        End With
        End If
    Next ws
    With Sheets(1)
        .Range("a3").Resize(i, 6).Value = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should really work on your sentence structure. Sentences like *"So If the the customer has doors and windows the sales person that should be retrieved is Jack If the customer has tiles and windows then the sales person that should be retrived is Sarah If the customer has windows, doors and tiles then the sales person that should be retrived is Sarah And if the customer has a single product then the name of the sales person retrieved should be the name of the person in the sales person column on that worksheet"* without punctuation are almost not understandable. Please improve your question

Comment: Thanks PEH. I have edited the question as requested.